# Asp.net MVC release config custom javascript issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, release

After publishing the website i am getting javascript errors like

```
TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined
```

Works fine when i switch to Degbug mode in web.config

any suggestion please.

**

> Update

**

Here is the final html output

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=OCFAn1NcaUrZ5VLi0Kt8lefDjHOF7mvtdw-2FUpZjJ01">
<script src="/bundles/zurb?v=bCGUiMpF-XN8v4h86_MNVwMElh2rda9wV-KjB32HHzI1">
<script src="/bundles/jqueryval?v=23P9NAiLRvyuRmVPUho09NX8j4Fx7j2ipaSeSYZ2-mY1">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.additional-methods.min.js">
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.creditcard2.pack-1.0.1.js">
<script src="/Scripts/startdateAdapters.js">
<script src="/Scripts/expiredateAdapters.js">
```

am i doing some thing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the properties of your Javascript file in the Solution Pane is flagged as "Content" to be published.

Check you bundles configuration, try removing the validator from the bundle for instance

Comment: Check the source code of your jqueryval?v=23P9NAiLRvyuRmVPUho09NX8j4Fx7j2ipaSeSYZ2-mY1 and see if it has the declaration of jquery.validator

Comment: TypeError: jQuery.validator is undefined its also not defined.

Comment: Check you bundles configuration, try removing the validator from the bundle for instance...

Comment: Yup that worked i think jquery validator has problem when being used in bundle or some thing like that

Comment: Ok, nice, changed my answer to consider the solution and close the problem. :)